# i have a next.js app and Python and FastAPI server , i need get posts from server , but get error when make a call

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, next.js, fastapi

when i call the api i get error back in the console :
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError'...} ,
i download axios on my app...
This is my first time using fast api , what can i do to solve this problem ?

when i call the api i get error back in the console :
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError'...} ,
i download axios on my app...
This is my first time using fast api , what can i do to solve this problem ?

//postsService.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const postsService = {
    fetchPosts
}

async function fetchPosts() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/posts')
        console.log(response);
        return response.data
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

//posts.jsx

```
"use client"

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { postsService } from "../services/postsService";

export default function page() {

  const [posts , setPosts] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async() => {
      const posts = await postsService.fetchPosts()
      setPosts(posts)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  console.log(posts);
  
  return (
    <div className="posts-container">
      <h1>Posts Page</h1>
      {/* Other content */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

//myApi.py

```
from typing import Union
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

posts = [
    {"id": 1, "title": "Test Post 1", "content": "<h1>Post 1</h1>"},
    {"id": 2, "title": "Test Post 2", "content": "<h1>Post 2</h1>"},
    {"id": 3, "title": "Test Post 3", "content": "<h1>Post 3</h1>"},
    {"id": 4, "title": "Test Post 4", "content": "<h1>Post 4</h1>"},
]



@app.get("/api/posts")
async def get_posts():
    # Logic to retrieve all posts from the database
    # Return a list of Post objects
    return posts
    
    
    
@app.get("/posts/{id}")
async def get_post(id: int):
    # Logic to retrieve a specific post by ID
    for post in posts:
        if post["id"] == id:
            return post
    # Return an error response if the post is not found
    return {"error": "Post not found"}


@app.get("/hp_data")
async def get_hp_data():
    # Logic to retrieve headline data for the homepage
    # Return a dict with the headline data
    return {"headline": "<h1>Welcome</h1>"}
```